# Graphql onCreate Subscription firing multiple times

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I have this on again off again error in react when using the `<Connect>` component to list and listen to mutations. Normally when I perform a create mutation the subscription should return 1 result which is what I just created but sometimes when I do this, the subscription returns several copies of thesame result and then I get the error

```
 prev.listPatients is undefined
```

Bellow you can see my connect component

```
<Connect
                            query={graphqlOperation(listPatients)}
                            subscription={graphqlOperation(onCreatePatient)}
                            onSubscriptionMsg={(prev, updatedQuery) => {
                              //console.log("checkme",updatedQuery)

                              //return prev; 

                              let updatedQuerys = {...prev};




                              var PatientList = [
                                  updatedQuery.onCreatePatient,

                                  ...prev.listPatients.items
                                ]

                              updatedQuerys.listPatients.items =  PatientList

                              console.log("checkme",prev)
                              console.log("checkmes",updatedQuerys)
                              console.log("checkmus",updatedQuery)



                              return updatedQuerys


                          }}
                          >
```

Hope someone knows what I can do against this.
Thanks!